# Java: Custom Exception Class with Multiple Exceptions

Tags: java, exception

I'm used to programming in `C++`, where you would declare multiple custom exceptions like so in a single class: [c++Exceptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ecpy.png), and you would call those custom exceptions with `throw new ExceptionEnumerationBeyondEnd()`.

How would I do this in Java?

From what I've learned in Java, one has to define each exception in it's own individual class. Is there anyway I can have an exceptions class that contains multiple custom exceptions as in `c++`, and just call a throw command when they get violated?

I plan on using it in a try catch block like this,

```
     try {

        if(...) throw new customException1();
        else ...

     } catch (customException1) {

     } catch (customException2) {

     } ...
```

Comment: That looks like multiple classes in your c++ example, not sure what you want accomplish here?

Comment: @Joakim, In C++, You can define new custom exceptions by making them classes like so in the header file I gave above, without defining class files for them. Then you can throw those exceptions by simply calling "throw new customException"... In that picture, I didn't write a single line of code defining any of those custom exceptions, those are all user defined in that example. I was wondering if there was a similar way to do so in java, and there seems to be a similar way to do so, if you see -StealthyCoder's answer, what he calls "Non-Conventional" is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to give a few examples in Java as I am unsure from the picture and your statement:

> where you would declare multiple custom exceptions like so in a single
>   class:

What you precisely mean with the declare multiple custom exceptions in a single class.

## Interface

In Java you can either define a `Interface` and implement that and use it in typing like so:

```
interface CustomException {
   String getMessage();
}
```

Then create a class that implements it.

```
class ApplicationException implements CustomException {
  public String getMessage() {
    return "Uh oh..";
  }
}
```

And when you throw anything you can get away with catching only `CustomException`.

```
try {
   // do something
}
catch( CustomException ce) {
  // do something with the CustomException
}
```

## Base class

The other way you can go is to extend one of the built in Exception classes like `RuntimeException` or just `Exception` itself.

```
class CustomException extends Exception {
  public CustomException(String message) {
    super(message);
  }
}
```

Then you can extend from that custom class and use it in typing as normal.

```
class ApplicationException extends CustomException {
  public ApplicationException(String message) {
    super(message);
  }
}
```

Then this works again like previously:

```
try {
   // do something
}
catch( CustomException ce) {
  // do something with the CustomException
}
```

Inside the catch you catch them all in one go. If you need to do different logic on different catches you can do separate `catch` blocks otherwise the other option you can do is:

```
try {
 // do something
}
catch ( ApplicationException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
  // do something with an error that is either a ApplicationException or a IllegalArgumentException
}
```

## Non conventional

This I am putting here for completeness sake but it is not conventional. You could create one file in your project called `Exception.java`. Inside you can define as many classes as you want and you can refer to them by importing them but it is not the idiomatic way to write Java.

So inside `Exception.java` :

```
class CustomException extends Exception {
  public CustomException(String message) {
    super(message);
  }
}

class ApplicationException extends Exception {
  public ApplicationException(String message) {
    super(message);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps you out and continues you on your journey.

Comment: @StealthyCoder, Thanks! The Non-Conventional way you gave is exactly what I was looking for! An exceptions class containing different types of custom exceptions! With more than 5 custom exceptions, I feel like the package or project would become cluttered with separate exception class files that only contain a couple of lines.